# Can I output video from my DSLR to a smartphone or iPad or laptop?

Tags: video

Pardon my ignorance on the subject; I have recently bought Sony A6000 to take video of my new borns. I have a question related to uncompressed output from this camera through HDMI. I know we can output video through this HDMI to a recording device like ATOMOS Ninja (or similar), but can we do same thing (output video) to a laptop or a smartphone or tablet (like iPad)?

I tried looking for similar question on StackExchange, but failed to find one which discusses on this exact matter. If there is any such discussion, could someone point me to that; I will try to understand from that discussion.

Thanks, NN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a relatively solid HDMI capture device to capture uncompressed HDMI output.  I'm not aware of any HDMI capture devices that will work with a phone or tablet, but there are options you could use with a laptop, such as the Black Magic Intensity, however, at that point, you are really probably better off going with a purpose built device such as the Black Magic HyperDeck Shuttle which takes a laptop SSD hard drive as media and records the uncompressed HDMI directly on to the drive for you.

The Shuttle will be more reliable, consume less power and be more portable than options involving a laptop and an HDMI capture interface (as well as likely being cheaper overall).

Answer (score 2):

You can to a laptop using an adapter (Blackmagic make some).

If you want something a bit more portable the Atmos Ninja (or similar) would be your best options.